# International characters in Python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I'm currently working on a Python script that takes a list of log files (from a search engine) and produces a file with all the queries within these, for later analysis.
Another feature of the script is that it removes the most common words, which I've also implemented, but I've faced a problem I can't seem to overcome. The removing of words does work as intended, as long as the queries does not contain special characters. As the search logs are in Danish, the characters æ, ø and å will appear regularly.

Searching on the topic I'm now aware that I need to encode these into UTF-8, which I'm doing when obtaining the query:

```
tmp = t_query.encode("UTF-8").lower().split()
```

t_query is the query and I split it up to later compare each word with my list of forbidden words. If I do not use the encoding I'll get the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe6 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**Edit:** I also tried using the decode instead, but get the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa7' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I loop through the words like this:

```
for i in tmp:
    if i in words_to_filter:
        tmp.remove(i)
```

As said this works perfectly for words not including special characters. I've tried to print the i along with the current forbidden word and will get e.g:

```
fÃ¦rdelsloven - færdelsloven
```

Where the first word is the ith element in tmp. The last word in the one from the forbidden words. Obviously something has gone wrong, but I just can't manage to find a solution. I've tried many suggestions found on Google and in here, but nothing have worked so far.

**Edit 2:** if it makes a difference, I've tried loading the log files both with and without the use of codec:

```
with codecs.open(file_name, "r", "utf-8") as f_src:
    jlogs = map(json.loads, f_src.readlines())
```

I'm running Python 2.7.2 from a Windows environment, if it matters. The script should be able to run on other platforms (namely Linux and Mac OS).

I would really appreciate if one of you are able to help me out.

Best regards
Casper

Comment: As a note, if you are working with unicode a lot, you might want to use 3.x if possible - it's Unicode support is much better.

Comment: Please read this: http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html - you have obviously little to almost no knowledge about encodings...

Comment: You might also what to read Joel Spolsky's [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: There's no reason to be rude. I've skimmed through that page before, but found nothing that could help me. If you could be so kind to point out exactly what you think could help me solve my problem, it would be appreciated.

Comment: For @ThomasK I do consider myself having basic knowledge of encoding - far from an expert though. That's why I find this problem strange, because, in my head, it shouldn't be hard to solve. I've just overlooked/misunderstood something. That's why I ask you guys to help out :)

Comment: Hi @Casper: Sorry, I wasn't trying to be rude. I just saw that you were trying both encode and decode, which is common behaviour for people who find the whole Unicode thing a bit mysterious. Step 1 is to be certain whether you've got bytes or unicode, e.g. by doing `print type(t_query)`.

Comment: @Lattyware: You can work with Unicode in Python 2 just fine. Python 3 just forces you to be more explicit about whether you want bytes or Unicode text.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Of course, I wasn't saying it wasn't possible, 3.x just makes it nicer to work with

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've finally solved it. As Lattyware Python 3.x seems to do much better. After changing the version and encoding the Python file to Unicode it works as intended.

Answer (score 4):

If you are reading files, you want to `decode` them.

```
tmp = t_query.decode("UTF-8").lower().split()
```

Comment: Decode on input, work with unicode internally, encode on output.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I already tried this, but thought it was wrong, since I got an error message:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa7' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0):

Given a utf-8 file with json object per line, you could read all objects:

```
with open(filename) as file:
    jlogs = [json.loads(line) for line in file]
```

Except for an embeded newline treatment the above code should produce the same result as yours:

```
with codecs.open(file_name, "r", "utf-8") as f_src:
    jlogs = map(json.loads, f_src.readlines())
```

At this point *all strings in `jlogs` are Unicode you don't need to do anything to handle "special" characters*. Just make sure you are not mixing bytes and Unicode text in your code.

- to get Unicode text from bytes: `some_bytes.decode(character_encoding)`
- to get bytes from Unicode text: `some_text.encode(character_encoding)`

Don't encode bytes/decode Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

If encoding is right and you just want to ignore unexpected characters you could use `errors='ignore'` or `errors='replace'` parameter passed to `codecs.open` function.

```
with codecs.open(file_name, encoding='utf-8', mode='r', errors='ignore') as f:
    jlogs = map(json.loads, f.readlines())
```

Details in docs:
http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data